# logging of OUI from wireless scanning

Tags: python, bash, sed, grep, wifi

Airodump-ng provides a --manufacturer flag, which queries an IEEE OUI file which is a flat text file with line by line descriptions of MAC addresses and the associated manufacturer.

However, this manufacturer information is not logged by airodump-ng, only displayed to screen while it is running.

The response on the Aircrack-ng forum was to use the .cap file generated by airodump, as the manufacturer is logged in there.

So I would greatly appreciate any advise on how to query the cap file in real time for manufacturers using regular expressions.

The device used is a Pineapple Mark V, so I am limited to the tooling provided by the Ash shell and the opkg repositories for wifi pineapple.

Or, failing that, advice on dumping the screen output from airodump-ng to a text file, again for later review and/or alerting on certain manufacturers being present.

Usual caveats apply - this is for use only on systems which I have permission to review - A campus in this instance.

Comment: There is also an 'information security' stack exchange site, I would post this there.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a OUI list ([here](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf) you have one from Wireshark) and then just match each MAC address you get from airodump-ng to a manufacturer using that list.